# How to JSON.serialize an opportunities line items?

Tags: json, serialization

How can I JSON.serialize an opportunities line items?

I need to create a single json file, that holds an oppty as well as it's line items.

If I just JSON.serialize(opportunity), I get all the Oppty's fields, but none of the line item data

```
{
"Probability": 100,
"IsWon": true,
"Type": "New Account - FIRST  (4 more) ...",
"OwnerId": "00AAI",
"QTY_of_Licences__c": 0,
"sfcloud__Expected_Re (8 more) ...": 2000.00,
"LastModifiedDate": "2014-03-10T13:12:54.000Z",
"Data_Quality_Score__ (1 more) ...": 60,
"support_end_date__c": "2015-03-05T00:00:00.000Z",
"Pricebook2Id": "01sD000000IAU",
"IsPrivate": false,
"testte__c": "2014-04-04T00:00:00.000Z",
"IsClosed": true,
"Hidden_Courier_URL__ (1 more) ...": "http://www.tex.c (2 more) ...",
"SystemModstamp": "2014-03-10T13:12:54.000Z",
"ForecastCategoryName": "Closed",
"ForecastCategory": "Closed",
"StageName": "Closed Won",
"Amount": 2000.00,
"CurrencyIsoCode": "USD",
"sfcloud__Bundle_Amou (5 more) ...": 0.00,
"LastModifiedById": "005200000I",
"sfcloud__Total_Amoun (4 more) ...": 2000.00,
"Direct_Sale__c": true,
"Payment_Due_Date__c": "2014-03-09T00:00:00.000Z",
"PO_Processed_Date__c": "2014-03-05T00:00:00.000Z",
"ExpectedRevenue": 2000.00,
"Opportunity_Number__ (1 more) ...": "201403-13167",
"Order_Processed__c": true,
"TotalOpportunityQuantity": 1.00,
"Name": "new name test",
"HasOpportunityLineIt (2 more) ...": true,
"Payment_Terms__c": "In Advance",
"Grand_Total__c": 2000.00,
"AccountId": "001M000000W1",
"CreatedById": "005200I",
"CreatedDate": "2014-03-05T09:58:59.000Z",
"VAT_Total__c": 0.00,
"CST_Total__c": 0.00,
"Opportunity__c": 1,
"Taxes_total__c": 0.00,
"IsDeleted": false,
"Id": "006M000Q",
"Data_Quality_Descrip (7 more) ...": "Missing: Lead Source (12 more) ...",
"CloseDate": "2014-03-05T00:00:00.000Z"
}
```

The only similar pair is:

```
"TotalOpportunityQuantity": 1.00
```

I need these as an array in my JSON that I send out.

so, how do I go by this?

Comment: Did you query the line items ?

Comment: No I did not query it.

Comment: @Saariko So that was an answer. Please, post your results when you are ready.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you do not explicitly query relation data, it will not be present in the sObject within apex, and thus not show up in the json version. If the data has been queried, the apex serialize method will include it.

Simplified example:

```
opportunity op = [SELECT id, (SELECT id
                              FROM opportunitylineitems) 
                 FROM opportunity 
                 WHERE name = 'TESTopp']; //dummy example in my dev org

system.debug(JSON.serialize(op));
```

this results:

```
{
    "attributes": {
        "type": "Opportunity",
        "url": "/services/data/v29.0/sobjects/Opportunity/006d0000006b2Iuxxx"
    },
    "OpportunityLineItems": {
        "totalSize": 2,
        "done": true,
        "records": [{
            "attributes": {
                "type": "OpportunityLineItem",
                "url": "/services/data/v29.0/sobjects/OpportunityLineItem/00kd0000004u29xxxx"
            },
            "OpportunityId": "006d0000006b2xxxx",
            "Id": "00kd0000004u2xxxx"
        }, {
            "attributes": {
                "type": "OpportunityLineItem",
                "url": "/services/data/v29.0/sobjects/OpportunityLineItem/00kd000000BVrdxxxx"
            },
            "OpportunityId": "006d0000006b2xxx",
            "Id": "00kd000000BVrdxxx"
        }]
    },
    "Id": "006d0000006b2Iuxx"
}
```